# How to create my own delay function in C

Tags: c, assembly, timedelay

I'm developing an OS and don't have access to the standard library. Therefore, I don't have access to `time.h`.

I'm using the following function to create a time delay.

```
void delay() {
    int c = 1 , d = 1 ;

    for ( c = 1; c <= 100000; c++) {
        for ( d = 1; d <= 100000; d ++) {
            asm("nop");
        }
    }
}
```

This waits around twenty seconds; however, I'd like the function to take in an integer and wait for that many seconds. What will I need to do to make this possible?

Comment: If you're developing an OS, you should look for timer hardware (at least for long waits). Ask the hardware to generate an interrupt, which you'll use to resume the process that asked for a delay.

Comment: If this is allowed to be approximate and hacky, divide the first 100000 by 20 (so it waits around one second) and multiply it by the number of seconds to wait. Otherwise, use actual timer hardware and interrupts.

Comment: this is a very broad subject, if you are doing a multi tasking OS, this delay is going to vary depending on other tasks running.   If this blocks the multitasking of your OS, then this is not so good.  Would be better to handle the sleep at your task scheduler using a good timer source.

Comment: You can't reliably use NOPs as a timing delay on a modern general purpose CPU. Just recompiling the code could have a big effect on the length of the delay, while running it another computer pretty much guarantees that the delay will be significantly different.

Answer (score 1):

Even 1 whole second is many orders of magnitude too long to busy-wait.  You definitely want to HLT the CPU to save power, and detect when your timer has expired in an interrupt handler.

But if you *really* want to busy-wait, a portable (across recent x86 CPUs) way use might be to use CPUID to find out how fast RDTSC ticks, and then loop PAUSE / RDTSC until you've reached your end-point timestamp.

That's really horrible, though.  Don't busy-wait.  x86 CPUs need to sleep so they can run at full turbo when there is something to do, not just at their sustained max clock speed.

Comment: He's probably on some embedded processor that can't not busy wait. If he's not, then this answer isn't all that helpful either as he needs to learn how `schedule()` needs to work instead.